# bash: jump to first argument

Tags: bash

This happens to me all the time: I type a long command line and forget to specify some options. For example:

```
$ tcpdump host foo.com and port 8080
```

Hmm, I should be seeing some output. Ah! Forgot to listen on a different interface.

At this point I'd hit the up-arrow to bring back the previous command, then either scroll back to the first argument or press C-a to jump to the start of the command and scroll forward to the first argument.

Is there a quicker way to jump to the first argument so I can insert the `-i eth1` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the closest shortcut without key rebindings is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> (<kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> in Mac).

Answer (score 3):

Command line editing can be done using either emacs style commands or vi style commands. The default is emacs (See [Jin's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/344308/bash-jump-to-first-argument/344311#344311)).

If you are more used to vi than emacs you can switch this editing mode in your ~/.bashrc file by adding `set -o vi` Then you can use any vi commands you are familiar with

<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> (start of line, end of word, append)
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> (start of line, next word, insert)
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> (go back 5 words, insert)
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> (find "h" going backwards, insert).
etc.